# ERROR: right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 19 links to 346956 instead of expected 346955 in index "pg_depend_reference_index"

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3, php-pgsql

I have a DB in postgres. The DB is big with total size over 4TB and over 500,000 tables and many indexes. The DB is over 4 yr old. 
Recently, the Pgsql DB server was not starting up, so I did the following to get it started again:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_resetxlog -f  /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data stop
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data start
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data stop
systemctl restart postgresql-9.3
```

Since then I am getting the following error whenever I try to create a new table in the DB:

```
mps_schools=> create table test_test(hello int);
ERROR:  right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 19 links to 346956 instead of expected 346955 in index "pg_depend_reference_index"
```

I have tried re-indexing the DB, but it doesnt work. What more can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pg_resetxlog` destroyed your database, which is something that can easily happen, which is why you don't call it just because you don't get the database started. It's something of a last ditch effort to get a corrupted database up.

What can you do?

1. Best solution: restore from a backup from before you ran `pg_resetxlog`.
2. Perform an offline backup of your database.

   Then start the database in single user mode:

   ```sh
   postgres --single -P -D /your/database/directory yourdbname
   ```

   Then try to reindex `pg_depend`:

   ```
   REINDEX TABLE pg_catalog.pg_depend;
   ```

   Exit the single user session, restart the database, run `pg_dumpall` to dump the database (and hope that it works), create a new database cluster with `initdb` and import the dump.

   Don't continue using the cluster where you ran `pg_resetxlog`.

Comment: I dont have a backup of the DB, so cannot do number 1. Will try and do number 2. Will this solution work ?https://lxadm.com/Repairing_broken_PostgreSQL_databases_/_tables

Comment: There are a few shortcomings in that procedure: `\d` will only list the tables on the `search_path`, so you might miss some tables. Also, if your system catalogs are damaged, `\d` might not work. If there is one message you should take home from this, it should be: backups are important.

Comment: I got fixed with your procedure 2. Thanks!!